# C# How to ensure the full load of a WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a control to which i added a custom behavior.

The behavior has two DependencyProperties:

```
public SomeObject Player {
    get { return (e)GetValue(PlayerProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PlayerProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Player.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty PlayerProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Player", typeof(IVideoPlayerDTO), typeof(PlayerStreamBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public IntPtr Handle {
    get { return (IntPtr)GetValue(HandleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HandleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Handle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty HandleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Handle", typeof(IntPtr), typeof(PlayerStreamBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(IntPtr.Zero, OnHandleChanged));
```

Each is binded to some object in WPF.
The problem is that the `OnHandleChanged` of the Handle property is activated before the control with the behavior is fully loaded which throws an exception while trying to add a HwndHost to the control.
How can i ensure the control is fully loaded before i try to add the HwndHost?
P.s: Tried to use `OnAttached()`, however this didn't work...

Comment: How is `OnHandleChanged` implemented? *[...] throws an exception [...]* pretty specific error description. -.- So what's it saying?

Comment: The error i get is:
"BuildWindowCore failed to return the hosted child window handle."
When i try to build the HandleRef:
HandleRef refhandle = new HandleRef(this, Player.Handle);
Everything goes ok, but when i try to return it to the method it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public MyControl()
{
    this.Loaded += MyControl_Loaded;
}

private void MyControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // Control is full loaded
}
```

Comment: Yeah Loaded event is fired when UserControl fully loaded

Comment: I can't use the Loaded event, because i'm in the behavior when i need to know if the AssociatedObject is loaded, and when i write: 
AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded; in the ctor of the behavior the AssociatedObject hasn't been create yet and it's null.